# use apple script to change app space pref based on external monitor plugged in or not

Tags: applescript, space, if-statement

Is there a way to use applescript to change an applications space preference based on whether or not an external monitor is plugged in?

I would like to open Microsoft RDC open in space 1 when the external monitor is plugged in but in space 2 when there is no external monitor present.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting space is difficult. You can find a list of things you can do with spaces [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=23453). That might tell you how to make the application open in a particular space. The other part is you need to know how many monitors you have attached at any particular time. Here's some code for that.

```
tell application "Automator Runner"
    set numberOfScreens to count of (call method "screens" of class "NSScreen")
end tell
```